# Keeping track of optimal indices while reducing a matrix by 1x1 each iteration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, matrix-indexing

**SETUP**

I have an NxN diagonal matrix and I shrink the matrix by 1x1 in each iteration.

```
indices = np.arange(0, np.size(n_n_matrix, 0)).tolist()
for iter in range(0, N-K)
    opt_indices = criterion(n_n_matrix)
    lost_index = [i for i in indices if i not in opt_indices][0]
    n_n_matrix = np.delete(traj_dist_matrix, lost_index, axis=0)
    n_n_matrix = np.delete(traj_dist_matrix, lost_index, axis=1)
```

I do this until I have a KxK diagonal matrix.
How can I keep track of the undeleted indices in terms of their position in the original NxN matrix?

**FAILURE**

I fail by trying:

```
lost_indices = [], list_indices_iter = []
>>>loop above<<<
    count_1 = sum(lost_index >= idx for idx in lost_indices_iter)
    count_2 = sum(lost_index + count_1 >= idx for idx in lost_indices_iter) - count_1
    ...
    lost_indices.append(lost_index + count_1 + count_2 ...)
    lost_indices_iter.append(lost_index)
left_opt_indices = [i for i in indices if i not in lost_indices]
```

**NARROW DOWN ISSUE**

My problem is illustrated by the following example: if I delete index *i*, the next matrix shrinks. If  I then delete index *j>=i* in the next iteration, I need to add *1* to *j* because its position decreased compared to the original NxN matrix. If I then delete index *k=>j*, I need to account for the two changes before, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** A friend of mine gave me a hint. Its a two-liner.

```
tracker_original_indices = np.arange(0, np.size(traj_dist_matrix, 0))
tracker_original_indices = np.delete(tracker_original_indices, lost_index, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but I'd keep track of a dictionary where the keys are the original index positions, and the values are the current index positions. I'm calling this the index_mapping

I've created a function to apply deletions to the index_mapping and show that you can create a list of the deletions and apply them all at the end, but you can also apply them one by one

Each deletion event is either in the x or y location and the index for the current array

```
def process_deletions(index_mapping, deletions):
    for deletion in deletions:
        del_kind = deletion['kind']
        del_ind = deletion['index']

        for orig_ind,curr_ind in index_mapping[del_kind].items():
            #Don't update an index if it's less than the one deleted
            if curr_ind < del_ind:
                continue

            #Set the deleted index to now be -1
            elif curr_ind == del_ind:
                index_mapping[del_kind][orig_ind] = -1

            #Otherwise if the index is greater than the one deleted
            #decrement the new index it points to
            #i.e. if index 3 is deleted, what was index 5 is now index 4
            else:
                index_mapping[del_kind][orig_ind] -= 1

    return index_mapping


num_rows = 10
num_cols = 10

#Start out that each original index points to it's same position in the unmodified matrix
index_mapping = {
    'x':{i:i for i in range(num_rows)},
    'y':{i:i for i in range(num_cols)},
}

#Keep track of all the deletions made
#Can alternatively make one deletion at a time and keep applying it to the index_mapping
deletions = [
    {'kind':'x', 'index':1},
    {'kind':'y', 'index':1},
    {'kind':'x', 'index':6},
    {'kind':'y', 'index':6},
    {'kind':'x', 'index':4},
    {'kind':'y', 'index':4},
]
index_mapping = process_deletions(index_mapping, deletions)

print(index_mapping)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works. Yet, I found an easier way, see above!